# Close a WCF persistent connection

Tags: c#, wcf, tcp

I have a problem with closing WCF persistent connection. I need not just to close an object, but close an established TCP connection.

What I have:

1. Many clients which can create a WCF connection like this:

   ```
   var binding = new BasicHttpBinding
   {
       CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
       ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
       SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
       OpenTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30)
   };  
   var endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress(comboBoxPath.Text);
   _factory = new ChannelFactory<IManagementService>(binding, endpointAddress);
   _multimodeService = _factory.CreateChannel();
   ```
2. Load Balancer with 2 servers.

What I need is just recreate a WCF connection after removing one server from LB. Case: many clients have persistent connections to both servers via LB. I want to exclude one server from LB, update it and return it back but all clients must work with other server during update period. So when I exclude server from LB and start an update all clients working with the first server started to get errors. They try to recreate a WCF connection but they can't, because I can't close a persistent WCF connection and LB continue to sent requests to he first server. If I could fully close the connection and create a new one LB would send a request to the second server.

I tried to create a small test application to establish WCF connection and look at it by a small utility CurrPorts. I see the connection when I get data from a server but all my attempts to close the connection were unsuccessful. I tied

```
((ICommunicationObject)_multimodeService).Close();
((ICommunicationObject)_multimodeService).Abort();
((IClientChannel)_multimodeService).Close();
((IClientChannel)_multimodeService).Abort();
_factory.Close();
_factory.Abort();
```

but it just dispose object in code. So after closing connection by any of this actions I can't get data until I open a connection again but an established TCP connection is still alive and reused after a creation of new connection. It is removed only after closing the application.
So the question: is it possible to fully close a persistent connection including TCP connection?

Note: I know about caching in ChannelFactory and tried to set a property

```
ClientBase<IManagementService>.CacheSetting = CacheSetting.AlwaysOff;
```

at the start of application but it hasn't helped either.
My framework version is 4.6.2.

Comment: Odd question  - what happens if you set the _multimodeservice and _factory to null after trying to close them?

Comment: Nothing has changed.